# Including Velocity.js within Foundation Sites

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, velocity.js

I'm trying to include Velocity.js within a Zurb Foundation Site.  However, when I try to build the site I was being presented with a build error within webpack.

In order to make sure it wasn't something to do with the site I was originally working on, I created a new installation.  Both seem to have the same issue. Am I missing something in a config, or why would the below error be presented?

**app.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import whatInput from 'what-input';
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
import 'velocity-animate/velocity.ui';

window.$ = $;

import Foundation from 'foundation-sites';
// If you want to pick and choose which modules to include, comment out 
the above and uncomment
// the line below
//import './lib/foundation-explicit-pieces';

$(document).foundation();
```

**error:**

```
[10:12:24] Error in plugin 'webpack-stream'
Message:
    ./~/velocity-animate/velocity.ui.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'velocity' in '/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity-animate'
resolve 'velocity' in '/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity-animate'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity-animate/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity-animate/package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity-animate/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/user/Sites/design/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/user/Sites/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/user/Sites/design/test/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/user/Sites/design/test/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /Users/user/Sites/design/test/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/velocity)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /Users/user/node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        No description file found
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/user/node_modules/velocity doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/user/node_modules/velocity.js doesn't exist
        .json
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/user/node_modules/velocity.json doesn't exist
        as directory
          /Users/user/node_modules/velocity doesn't exist
[/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity-animate/node_modules]
[/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/node_modules]
[/Users/user/Sites/design/node_modules]
[/Users/user/Sites/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/user/node_modules/package.json]
[/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity]
[/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity.js]
[/Users/user/node_modules/velocity/package.json]
[/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity.json]
[/Users/user/node_modules/velocity]
[/Users/user/Sites/design/test/node_modules/velocity]
[/Users/user/node_modules/velocity.js]
[/Users/user/node_modules/velocity.json]
[/Users/user/node_modules/velocity]
 @ ./~/velocity-animate/velocity.ui.js 19:2-31
 @ ./src/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./src/assets/js/app.js
Details:
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this open issue](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/743), you can't import velocity in this fashion yet. [This comment](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/743#issuecomment-332859429) says to do it like this instead for now:

```
window.Velocity = require('velocity-animate');
require('velocity-animate/velocity.ui');
```